# C++ directed nearest neighbor sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, nearest-neighbor

So in my code I get the xyz coordinates of points, which should form a contour. The problem is that this points aren't sorted in a correct way. When I get the coordinates They are sorted by rising x and y values. So first the x values are sorted, and if two points have the same x value they are sorted by their y value. The z value is always the same, so it can be ignored.
To sort the points to form the contour, I use a variation of the nearest neighbor algorithmen.
So here's my code for sorting:

```
double squareDistancePoints(const std::array<double, 3>& a, const std::array<double, 3>& b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    double sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        sum += pow(b[i]-a[i], 2);
    return sum;
}


for(auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it)
{
    auto bestIt = matrix.end();

    double bestSquareDistance = DBL_MAX;

    for(auto nextIt = it + 1; nextIt != matrix.end(); ++nextIt)
    {
        const auto squareDistance = squareDistancePoints(*it, *nextIt);
        if( squareDistance < bestSquareDistance)
        {
            bestSquareDistance = squareDistance;
            bestIt = nextIt;
        }
    }
    if(bestIt != matrix.end())
    {
        std::swap(*(it + 1), *bestIt);
    }

}
```

So this works perfectly for standard contours, like a cube or a circle. But I also got contours, where this won't work.
So here's a picture of a unsorted contour
[image]

When I use the sorting code I provided I receive this result:
[image]

I already found the problem in the idea of my code. The contour is substantially longer than it is wide, thus the sorting algorithm is also always the nearest point on the wrong place.
So the correct picture would look like this:

[image]

My approach here was to start with one point, search for the nearest point and the follow the direction the points gave me. I did this all manually.
So my problem now is I don't know how to optimize my code so it follows a direction when sorting.
I hope somebody can help me. I also could send a .csv file with the unsorted and sorted points, if thath would help.

Answer (score 0):

you're accessing wrong data area here when it is in the last iteration: `(it + 1)==matrix.end()` in that case => undefined behaviour.

```
for(auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it)
{
    ...
    if(bestIt != matrix.end())
    {
        std::swap(*(it + 1), *bestIt);
    }
```

Comment: could that undefined behavior lead to the wrong result? Or is this just another mistake? Because for regular contours, like squares and circles, this works perfectly fine

Comment: UB happens only if `(bestIt != matrix.end())`. Maybe it does not happen in squares or circles. You tell me (add a print or use the debugger)

Comment: I just made a example code so you can see what I'm doing. [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMT2RNOEx0ODU2NFU)

Comment: even with my fix your code crashes with segfault using that link! time to debug.

Comment: I edited my code, now I get no error messages, when I execute the code [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVHZEZHBzdWFtUkk)